# Why is an edit, that reduces the inaccuracy of an answer, rolled back?

Tags: discussion, edits, rollbacks

I'm not earning rep by editing answer/questions anymore. If I do, I do it with the best intentions and because I struggled myself to grasp some concept.

This post is about an edit I did on [a Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60054547/convert-u-to-t-without-changing-headers-in-a-fasta/60054825#60054825), which consisted of adding a link [to Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63891/what-is-the-meaning-of-1-at-the-end-of-awk-script/392555#392555).

I was a bit surprised when I saw an `awk` statement ending by `}1` for the first time. Then I searched a bit, and I found [this clear, detailed explanation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63891/what-is-the-meaning-of-1-at-the-end-of-awk-script/392555#392555). Oh, now I know how it works.

Then I end up on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60054547/convert-u-to-t-without-changing-headers-in-a-fasta) tagged both `awk` and `sed`, and I told myself "If the answer(s) only use either program, I'll answer using the other one". No way, [a very good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60054547/convert-u-to-t-without-changing-headers-in-a-fasta/60054825#60054825) exists already which gives both alternatives. So far so good.

Then I notice that the `awk` part of the answer ends by:

> That last `1` is not a typo; it's an Awk idiom for "print all lines".

Well, this is actually misleading, as it connects `1` to a verb, *print*; in fact, that `1` has nothing to do with the lines,  it incidentally relates to *all lines*, and definitely it has even less to do with printing, or with any other action. In short, this sentence is at least misleading and smoky (all the smoke tentatively hidden behind the word *idiom*).

Do I add a new question? No, I will just **append** a link to [that UnixSE answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63891/what-is-the-meaning-of-1-at-the-end-of-awk-script/392555#392555), without altering anything else, because the answer is high quality. And the author knows for sure the truth about `1`.

The edit is rolled back **and put in a comment**. Why? Isn't [clarifying the meaning of a post without changing it, correcting minor mistakes, adding related resources or hyperlinks](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) encouraged?

Well, the text of my edit was *([full story of `1`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63891/what-is-the-meaning-of-1-at-the-end-of-awk-script/392555#392555))*. Maybe it sounded a bit Indiana Jones, I don't know, but the original answerer, @tripleee, could have incorporated the edit as he likes **in the answer**, so as to avoid a reader going away with the misconception that `1` prints stuff in `awk`.

How can an edit, which is short, concise, appended, and clarifying, be considered invasive or "not worth it"?

Comment: hmmmm... if this is to discuss the specific edit here.... it's better to go on meta.unix.  If this is to discuss more in general terms (which your question doesn't seem to angle itself for), then this would be okay

Comment: Note this should be asked either on the site-specific meta or maybe the global meta, not metaSO.

Comment: The answer I edit is on SO, and it is linked.

Comment: @Enrico "unix.stackexchange.com" is not "stackoverflow.com".... or your links are confusing?

Comment: @Patrice, that is the answer I linked in the SO answer I edited.

Comment: I agree with [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60054547/convert-u-to-t-without-changing-headers-in-a-fasta/60054825#comment106227704_60054825).

Comment: @Enrico yeah just clicked through all the links and everything and did find the stack. My bad there. But.... I must say then this may be confusing, as people focus (like I did) on the wrong link it seems. jon made a similar mistake :/. Maybe a bit of a rewrite to focus differently would be in order.

Comment: @Patrice, I've added a line explaining the relation between the two links.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's their answer.

They can rollback your edits if they do not agree with them. If they do not want that link in their answer, it's up to them.

End of story.

Comment: I did something similar recently. A couple sentence corrections but the edit message was a link to sentence structuring blog/correction site so I no longer wanted it on my answer :P petty, but my choice

Comment: @SterlingArcher, _no longer_? What do you mean? Has there been a moment you wanted it and something triggered your change of mind?

Comment: @Enrico it's explained, maybe just hard to grasp:Sterling saw the edit, saw it improved his post with grammar and stuff. Then he saw the edit message that was only a link to a correction site. He maybe felt insulted, talked down to, or basically being talked to condescendingly. So he decided that he didn't wanna have that anymore.

Comment: @Patrice, only now I understand (I hope) that the _edit message_ is what you put in the _edit summary_ field before confirming the edit. Thanks for repeating it.

Comment: @Patrice not everyone likes Peter's changes :) I like them as I just for the life of me can't put enough of *a* articles into *the* post... But indeed link in the edit comment he provides is not edit specific and may put someone off.

Comment: @SterlingArcher Isn’t it still there in the edit history?

Comment: @BSMP it sure is

Answer (score 10):

As the author of the discussed post who decided to roll back the edit, I'll just point out that I left [a comment,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60054547/convert-u-to-t-without-changing-headers-in-a-fasta/60054825#comment106227704_60054825) which is already linked from some comments on this questions; but I'll inline it here:

> @EnricoMariadeAngelis I rolled back your edit as somewhat invasive. I'm fine with linking to https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/63891/19240 in a comment

My beef with the edit was mainly that it linked to [a soapbox-style answer which dislikes this idiom](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/392555/19240) and secondarily that it felt like it was putting words in my mouth that I didn't want there (how is this a "full story"? That it is not). I suppose I could have edited the post to reduce this effect (link to the question instead, and tweak the wording of the link) but eventually rolling back and leaving a comment just felt like the simpler solution to a very small problem.

Comment: Thanks for bringing this up on meta, though I would also have appreciated a ping with a link here in a comment.

Comment: Sorry for not tagging you (I could have done it from that post, not from this, [right](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020/335205)?). Anyway, beef eaten. I tend to evaluate answers (when voting/linking/whatever them) only based on their technical content (and my judgement can be involuntarly erroneous/inaccurate; as in, maybe that was not the _full_ story), not on possible non-technical hidden soapbox-style messages. I should have thought that you could have a different view, I am sorry. If I'll ever think about improving a question of yours I'll leave a comment.

Comment: No harm in submitting an edit; be bold.

Comment: On **your** Q/As? Only if you promise you'll not punish me with downvotes.

Comment: I don''t think I have downvoted any content of yours. Edits can't be voted on anyway. Like you yourself suggest, I reserve the right to judge individual posts on their technical merit alone; but if you mean "no revenge voting" you absolutely and definitely have my promise (although it should already be covered by the Code of Conduct etc).

Comment: I hope not, since lastly my content were no that bad, I think. However, it was meant to be a joke (referring to revenge voting, yes) to say _ok, if you say so, I'll not ask before editing you, should I do it in the future_.